# Adding columns to an existing Pandas DataFrame from a list of arrays

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have three different things I would like to add to a DataFrame. The first two are simple arrays. The third is a list of arrays. Let's assume this is a very long list of arrays and I cannot simply break up this list. All arrays are the same length.

I have tried to simply use pandas.concat, but this does not work when one of the elements is a list of arrays.

```
import pandas as pd

a = [0, 4, 6, 8]
b = [5, 8, 9, 7]

c = [0, 5, 8, 4], [5, 8, 9, 1], [8, 9, 9, 9]

q = pd.concat([a, b, c])
```

This above coded will return an error with the sizes because it is trying to join c as it's own column. I need these arrays as a column for a, a column for b, and three different columns for the arrays in c.

Comment: Are they lists or arrays? Can you please clarify? Also, do all subarrays in c have the same length?

Comment: c is a list of three arrays. All subarrays have the same length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `extend` to add in an arbitrary number of lists from `c`.

```
all_data = [a, b]
all_data.extend(c)
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data).T
```